# Image misalignment issues with CSS grid

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid

I've been looking for a while now, and I can't find an answer that seems to work.

I have some cards, with two images inside them.

[image]

The images inside the cards are *slightly* different aspect ratios - which leaves a little bit of unwanted white space, and uneven horizontal spacing. Essentially, how do I get rid of that? :)

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVMQJV) to help explain it a little better.

Is the best way to go about this declare heights for everything and some sort of zoom approach?

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card-image-profile {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.card-image-department {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  max-width: 70%
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .card-image-department {
    max-width: 100%
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="card-image-profile">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x60" class="card-image-department">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/359x150" class="card-image-profile">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x60" class="card-image-department">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/345x150" class="card-image-profile">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x60" class="card-image-department">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/357x150" class="card-image-profile">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x62" class="card-image-department">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="card-image-profile">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x60" class="card-image-department">
  </div>
</main>
```

[image]

The spacing isn't consistent between the cards - due to the slightly different image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

This code might solve your problem but if it is not let me know.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card-image-profile {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 109px;
}

.card-image-department {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  //max-width: 70%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .card-image-department {
    //max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="card-image-profile">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x60" class="card-image-department">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/359x150" class="card-image-profile">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x60" class="card-image-department">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/345x150" class="card-image-profile">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x60" class="card-image-department">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/357x150" class="card-image-profile">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x62" class="card-image-department">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="card-image-profile">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x60" class="card-image-department">
  </div>
</main>
```

I just changed 3 classes:
First One:

```
.card-image-department {  
  padding: 0.25rem; 
  //max-width: 70%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Second one is:

```
.card-image-profile{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 109px;
}
```

And the last one just comment the code in @Media class:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .card-image-department {
    //max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: How does the code solve the problem? What was the asker doing wrong? Please explain your answers on Stack, don’t just dump code

Comment: Dear friend I add some extra information if its not satisfying you. I think I can explain more.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set width and height to 100% for card-image-department. You had the max-width set at 70% which should be removed.

```
.card-image-department {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the space between the images you should remove the padding property in the .card-image-department class. With respect to the horizontal space, itshould be already center with the place-items: center; in the card class, I don't see how can be uneven.